# How to watch for notification & process in background thread?

Tags: cocoa

So basically what I am looking to do create a background thread where all it does is watch for a notification to be posted and then do some processing on it when it is posted. I havn't been able to find a way to do this.  Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably NSNotificationCenter's -addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock. I would try that first, but I believe there have been some issues with that, so here's an alternative if it doesn't meet your needs:

```
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(processNotificationInBackground:) name:TheNameOfTheNotification object:nil];
...

- (void) processNotificationInBackground:(NSNotification *)not {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        /* your background notification processing code goes here */
        /* note that you should transfer control back to the main queue if you need to update your UI */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  I think that this is a step in the right direction, however, from what I can tell by implementing these methods, they still require main (or whatever thread they are implemented in) to be unblocked to process the notification and dispatch the background thread.  I would prefer to do both the monitoring for the notification and the processing in a background thread that is always running.

Comment: Not sure I see the point of that (shouldn't you be leaving your main thread unblocked to avoid beachballs?), but I would expect if you post a notification to a notification center on a background thread, it will process it on that thread rather than shuttling it over to the main one. All you need to do then is make your notification *posters* do so on the background thread, which is simple enough. Double check though; not sure on if that behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: I'm not blocking my main thread, I just have some essential things going on in my main thread that I don't want to interrupt. Thanks for the help though. I think that you are right about posting to the background thread. Thanks!